# get network interface information C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, ifconfig

I am beginner in programming.  I work with Eclipse  C++ in Linux Ubuntu.  I know there is `ifconfig` command to list network interface info.  I want code to get information about a network interface and print this information.

In other words, how can I write the code that performs the `ifconfig` command with c++?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get some of the info out of [getifaddrs()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) but there is more to it than that so you have your work cut out.  Why not look the source for `ifconfig` for starters?

Comment: i think getifaddrs() for socket programming with c. however i want code with c++.
i dont know how can use this function in my code.
how can find "source for ifconfig for starters"?